# How to test if file IO is changed according to time with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a class like this.

```
class Time
  def has_same_hours?(t)
    self.strftime("%Y%m%d%H") == t.strftime("%Y%m%d%H")
  end
end
class MyLogger
  DATA_DIR = 'data'
  def initialize
    @time_current_hour = Time.now
    @io = nil
    update_io_to_current_hour
  end
  def update_io_to_current_hour
    @io = open output_filename, "a+" if @io.nil?
    return if @time_current_hour.has_same_hours? Time.now
    @io.close
    @io = open output_filename, "a+"
    @time_current_hour = Time.now
  end
  def output_filename(time = Time.now)
    "#{DATA_DIR}/#{time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H')}.txt"
  end
end
```

When `update_io_to_current_hour` is called, the file IO should be changed if hour is different  compare to `@time_current_hour`.

I want to write RSpec test for it. This is what I wrote.

```
describe Logger do
  let(:logger){ Logger.new }
  describe "#update_io_to_current_hour" do
    context "when the hour changes" do
      before{
        @time_now = Time.parse("2010/4/10 19:00")
        @time_current = Time.parse("2010/4/10 18:59")
        Time.stub(:now).and_return(@time_now)
        logger.stub(:time_current_hour).and_return(@time_current)
      }
      it "should change file io" do
        expect{logger.update_io_to_current_hour}.to change{ logger.instance_variable_get :@io }
      end
    end
    context "when the hour doesn't changes" do
      before{
        @time_now = Time.parse("2010/4/10 18:59")
        @time_current = Time.parse("2010/4/10 18:58")
        Time.stub(:now).and_return(@time_now)
        logger.stub(:time_current_hour).and_return(@time_current)
      }
      it "should not change file io" do
        expect{logger.update_io_to_current_hour}.not_to change{ logger.instance_variable_get :@io }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Second test passes and first not. It looks like file io is never changed whatever stubbed to `Time` object.

What am I doing wrong? How can I write the test properly?

Comment: isn't confusing to name the method has_same_hours? when you are checking just the opposite?

Comment: You are right, I should check with `==` not `!=`. I don't know why I missed that kind of mistake. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points:

```
logger.stub(:time_current_hour)
```

The class has no method named `:time_current_hour`, only an instance variable. There is rarely a good reason to test the values of instance variables; that is an implementation detail. You want to test behavior. In any case this stub is ineffective. Also

```
logger.instance_variable_get :@io
```

Now you are reaching right into the guts of your object and inspecting its internal values. Have you no regard for its privacy? :)

I think this would be a lot easier if you simply tested the value of `:output_filename`. When the hour changes, the filename changes. When the hour is the same, the filename is the same.

Comment: So, I shouldn't test instance variables directly, I understand. And I already have the test for `:output_filename`, I'll simply get rid of this test. Thanks for explanation!